# How to can I parse this json?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to parse [the Json result returned from this url](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3Ftitle%20%3Fcontent%20%3Fthumbnail%20%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fs%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel.%0D%0A%3Flabel%20bif%3Acontains%20%27SOAP%27%40en.%0D%0A%3Fs%20dbpedia-owl%3AwikiPageDisambiguates%20%3Fy.%0D%0A%3Fy%20dbpedia-owl%3Aabstract%20%3Fcontent.%0D%0A%3Fy%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Ftitle%0D%0Aoptional%7B%0D%0A%3Fy%20dbpedia-owl%3Athumbnail%20%3Fthumbnail.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afilter%28langmatches%28lang%28%3Fcontent%29%2C%22en%22%29%29%0D%0Afilter%28langmatches%28lang%28%3Flabel%29%2C%22en%22%29%29%0D%0Afilter%28langmatches%28lang%28%3Ftitle%29%2C%22en%22%29%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder%20by%20desc%28%3Fthumbnail%29&format=application%2Fsparql-results%2Bjson&timeout=30000&debug=on). I want to get title, content and thumbnail value. I tried to make a java class to Map those values .

```
import java.util.List;

public class Dbpediaresults {

  private Results results;

  public Results getResults() {
    return results;
  }

  public void setResults(Results results) {
    this.results = results;
  }

  public static class Results {
    private List<Bindings> bindings;

    public List<Bindings> getBindings() {
      return bindings;
    }

    public void setBindings(List<Bindings> bindings) {
      this.bindings = bindings;
    }

  }

  public static class Bindings {
    private List<Title> title;
    private List<content> content;
    private List<Thumbnail> thumbnail;

    /**
     * @return the title
     */
    public List<Title> getTitle() {
      return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(List<Title> title) {
      this.title = title;
    }

    public List<content> getContent() {
      return content;
    }

    public void setContent(List<content> content) {
      this.content = content;
    }

    public List<Thumbnail> getThumbnail() {
      return thumbnail;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(List<Thumbnail> thumbnail) {
      this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

  }

  private static class Title {
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
      return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

  }

  private static class content {
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
      return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }

  private static class Thumbnail {
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
      return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }

}
```

I tried this to get the result but it isn't working.

```
Dbpediaresults results = new Gson().fromJson(input, Dbpediaresults.class);
```

Here input is a `String` of the json output returned from URL above.

Is my `Dbpediaresults` class is correct to map the title, content and thumbnail value? If not, how can I parse it correctly?

Comment: Usually JSON->Java mappers will complain if something is not right during the mapping.  Did you get any exceptions?

Comment: i got null value in results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson will not break the `Binding` group into three separate lists like that. The easiest way to fix this would be to create containing a single `List<Binding>`, where `Binding` is a class that represents all three of title, content, and thumbnail. It's better to keep these together anyway as multiple parallel `List`s are a [strong hint that there's a class waiting to be born.](http://www.coderanch.com/t/383868/java/java/Sorting-set-arrays)

Here's some sample code. In addition to fixing the problem, I made some other minor style and variable name changes (such as `class Content` being lowercase in your code, and removing the setters).

```
public class Dbpediaresults {
  private Results results;

  public Results getResults() {
    return results;
  }

  public void setResults(Results results) {
    this.results = results;
  }

  public static class Results {
    private List<Binding> bindings;

    public List<Binding> getBindings() {
      return bindings;
    }
  }

  public static class Binding {
    private Title title;
    private Content content;
    private Thumbnail thumbnail;

    public Title getTitle() {
      return title;
    }
    public Content getContent() {
      return content;
    }
    public Thumbnail getThumbnail() {
      return thumbnail;
    }
  }

  public static class Title {
    private String value;
    public String getValue() {
      return value;
    }
  }

  public static class Content {
    private String value;
    public String getValue() {
      return value;
    }
  }

  public static class Thumbnail {
    private String value;
    public String getValue() {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i use the result in java program.

Comment: @user2400582 I don't understand what you're asking me. Just use the provided code instead of your `Dbpediaresults` class that your gave me.

Comment: i tried modified class and use this Dbpediaresults results = new Gson().fromJson(input, Dbpediaresults.class); to get result but still results is null.

Comment: @user2400582 I tested it on my own machine, it worked correctly. Are you certain the library you're using to get the page is working correctly? Try doing `System.out.println(input)` and see if it's giving the results you expect.

Comment: oops my mistake wrongly added null before input string .